# Help me fix a gap between tile and baseboard!

Tags: tile

I just removed the paneling in my den. When I started with the base boards and noticed that when when my tile was installed they were installed with the base boards in place. Before I could remove the base boards I had to actually break the grout around them so I could get the boards out. Now that that is done I now have a 3/4 inch gap between the wall and the tile and that is only one side of the room. The other side will have about an inch and a half gap. How should I address this. I was thinking of getting some grout to match and filling this gap in. Not sure if that is the best solution. [image]

Comment: Who did your tile job?

Comment: Is the exposed area at the sub floor level?

Answer (score 1):

You have a 3/4" gap and a 1 1/2" gap, and clearly the larger gap is too wide to be covered by a baseboard alone.

What I might try to do is see if you can get a standard baseboard against the wall which will give you about 3/4", then I would put quarter round right after that against the baseboard.

[image]

The 1.5" gap will be hidden, but you might need to cut a 3/4" wide strip of wood so the quarter round has something to sit on.  It should be roughly the same height of the tile so the edge of the quarter round will be just covering the edge of the tile.  If there any more gaps at this point I would probably get some white paintable caulk and go around the base of the quarter round.

I like this approach because I think a little quarter round around the baseboards of your room can be quite aesthetically pleasing and make a simple boring looking baseboard look even nicer.

Comment: I really like the look of the baseboard with the quarter round. Would the baseboard fit inside the gap or should it be sitting on the tile?  If its suppose to sit on the tile what would I put in the gap to make it even with the tile

Comment: @Cindy It really all depends on the type and style of the baseboard and if it would look silly or stupid sitting on the subfloor.  If you want the baseboard to sit on a small piece of wood to be level with the tile then it depends on how high the tile sits on the subfloor.  If it is about 3/4" thick then cutting some 1x? dimensional lumber would sit about even with the tile and allow the baseboard to sit flush.  The point of the quarter round is really to look nice while hiding ugliness that is on and near the bottom of the baseboard.

Answer (score 0):

I think 1 1/2 inches is too much for grout.  I would cut a matching gap on the 3/4 inch side and add a contrasting border 1 1/2 inches around the room.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this will work with the seams being uneven.  What a wreck of a tile job she had.  Probably just put existing tile pieces in.

Comment: I'm suggesting making the gap EVEN by cutting the gap to 1 1/2 all around.

Comment: Getting a clean cut on installed tile is hard.  They couldn't even tile right.  I wouldn't do this.

Comment: Yes, its hard, but having the right tools and technique .., I just happen to have a 3 1/2 inch diamond blade tile cutting circular saw with water connections for dustless cutting, a shop vac that converts to water pickup, and, and.

Comment: It was a company that lays saltio tile. It was done around 3 yrs ago. Yes you can see the sub floor. My thought was to grout the add a trim. The grout line all around is so uneven. Some of the grout is maybe about 1/8th inch all the way to 1 1/2 in. It's crazy. What even crazier. Is that I did even notice until I starting doing some work in that room. I have pocket doors in that room and I can't even close them because the tile is to high. So they are in the open position inside the walls. Frustrated to say the least. The company is no longer in business. Surprise!